# The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint ... but there's no conflicting data!

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, sql-server-2019

**Short version**

Q: Is there a bug like [kb4503379](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4503379-fix-referential-integrity-constraints-are-not-evaluated-correctly-when-query-execution-plan-uses-foreign-key-reference-check-operator-in-sql-server-2016-and-2017-a6910473-265a-b597-2aad-79e4137cbdf6) in SQL 2019 v15.0.2095.3.

A: Yes, seems like it. Install [v15.0.4236.7](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5014353-description-of-the-security-update-for-sql-server-2019-cu16-june-14-2022-f0afe659-bd19-4c87-a417-a4c67a47e644) and the problem goes away.

**Original Long version**

I understand foreign keys and referential integrity, but I'm hitting a problem like [this bug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4503379-fix-referential-integrity-constraints-are-not-evaluated-correctly-when-query-execution-plan-uses-foreign-key-reference-check-operator-in-sql-server-2016-and-2017-a6910473-265a-b597-2aad-79e4137cbdf6) where DELETEs can fail when they should succeed. However, that was for SQL 2016 & 2017 and I'm on 2019. Are there similar bugs on SQL 2019? I'm using SQL 2019 Developer edition v15.0.2095.3. (*Spoiler: upgrading fixed it*)

My problem is I'm hitting this error, but there *is no data in the table causing the conflict*. If I drop *other tables* then the problem goes away, just like in the bug mentioned above.

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 11
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag_Reference". The conflict occurred in database "Tenant_XXXX", table "planData.p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag", column 'ReferenceId'.
```

I know, it sounds like I'm just not looking correctly, but there's really no data that should cause the constraint violation.

There are two main tables of interest `dbo.Reference` (parent table) and `planData.p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag` (child table). When I run this SQL I get the error:

```
begin tran 

-- delete the referencing data (several thousand rows)
delete from planData.p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag 
where ReferenceId = 14

-- check it's not there. This returns 0 rows. 
select * from planData.p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag 
where ReferenceId = 14

-- But this fails with FK error!?
delete from dbo.Reference
where ReferenceId = 14
```

Table definitions are further below, but `dbo.Reference` has an identity primary key of `ReferenceId` and `planData.p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag` has a foreign key from its `ReferenceId` column to `dbo.Reference.ReferenceId`. So far nothing strange.

However, there are a total of 404 tables similar to `planData.p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag` that also reference `dbo.Reference.ReferenceId`. If I drop all of them except for planData.p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag and then run the statements above THEN NO ERROR OCCURS! This makes me think it's a problem just like [kb4503379](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4503379-fix-referential-integrity-constraints-are-not-evaluated-correctly-when-query-execution-plan-uses-foreign-key-reference-check-operator-in-sql-server-2016-and-2017-a6910473-265a-b597-2aad-79e4137cbdf6).

Some other points:

- There is no other activity on the db, this is running on a development db on my dev machine.
- both tables are system-versioned temporal tables with server-generated history tables. I tried removing SYSTEM_VERSIONING and that didn't appear to make a difference.
- I tried setting compatibility level to 130 and that didn't appear to make a difference
- I don't know how to see the query plan for my DELETE that fails so I can't check if the same problem as in that SQL bug is happening now. Any tips?
- I've run a DBCC CHECKDB and ALTER TABLE x REBUILD on the two tables, with no change to the outcome.
- As you can see, one table is in dbo schema and the other in planData.
- I've double-checked there are no other tables with very similar-looking names and no other foreign keys with very similar-looking names, so it's not just a name confusion problem. Or not one I can see.

I should get SQL Server updates via windows updates but I see I'm not on the latest version so will try to fix that now.

Table create scripts are below:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reference](
    [ReferenceId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PlanId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [EditUserId] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [SysStartTime] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    [SysEndTime] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Reference] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ReferenceId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([SysStartTime], [SysEndTime])
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
WITH
(
SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[Reference_History])
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Reference]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Reference_Plan] FOREIGN KEY([PlanId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Plan] ([PlanId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Reference] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Reference_Plan]
GO

CREATE TABLE [planData].[p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag](
    [ReferenceId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [d_Distriktsbolag_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [d_KontoDistriktsbolagen_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [d_Period_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [d_Specifikation_Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DecimalValue] [decimal](38, 18) NOT NULL,
    [EditLogId] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [SysStartTime] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    [SysEndTime] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
    [ClientRowId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [UQ_p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag_ReferenceAndDimensions] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ReferenceId] ASC,
    [d_Distriktsbolag_Id] ASC,
    [d_KontoDistriktsbolagen_Id] ASC,
    [d_Period_Id] ASC,
    [d_Specifikation_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([SysStartTime], [SysEndTime])
) ON [PRIMARY]
WITH
(
SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [planData].[p0010_hvtr_OutputDistriktsbolag])
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [planData].[p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag_Distriktsbolag] FOREIGN KEY([d_Distriktsbolag_Id])
REFERENCES [planData].[p0010_d_Distriktsbolag] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [planData].[p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag_Distriktsbolag]
GO

ALTER TABLE [planData].[p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag_KontoDistriktsbolagen] FOREIGN KEY([d_KontoDistriktsbolagen_Id])
REFERENCES [planData].[p0010_d_KontoDistriktsbolagen] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [planData].[p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag_KontoDistriktsbolagen]
GO

ALTER TABLE [planData].[p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag_Period] FOREIGN KEY([d_Period_Id])
REFERENCES [planData].[p0010_d_Period] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [planData].[p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag_Period]
GO

ALTER TABLE [planData].[p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag_Reference] FOREIGN KEY([ReferenceId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Reference] ([ReferenceId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [planData].[p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag_Reference]
GO

ALTER TABLE [planData].[p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag_Specifikation] FOREIGN KEY([d_Specifikation_Id])
REFERENCES [planData].[p0010_d_Specifikation] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [planData].[p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag_Specifikation]
GO
```

Comment: Can post the *estimated* execution plan for the `delete` batch? Also the DDL you posted is incomplete: there are a large number of undefined referenced tables

Comment: Ah yes, I was trying to get the Actual plan but the error prevented it. Sadly now that I've upgraded the problem has gone away and I don't have an older engine to test it on, and probably the bugfix causes the plan to differ. The DDL of the 403 other referencing tables is the same as for `p0010_vtr_OutputDistriktsbolag` but with differing int columns d_XXX_Id. Now I've confirmed it's fixed with 15.0.4236.7 there seems little point scripting & posting it.

Comment: Probably is still, it's worth documenting a bug fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be issue [13607143](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/kb4570012-cumulative-update-7-for-sql-server-2019-87ea390d-0def-6173-efd2-f6be8549d77d#bkmk_13607143), which was fixed in SQL Server 2019 CU7

> DELETE statement returns Foreign Key check constraint error even when REFERENCE table has no matching rows.
> **Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line LineNumber
> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "ConstraintName".
>
> The conflict occurred in database "DatabaseName", table "TableName", column 'ColumnName'.
>
> The statement has been terminated.**

Under exactly what circumstances this is triggered is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the latest cumulative update & security update [KB5014353](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5014353-description-of-the-security-update-for-sql-server-2019-cu16-june-14-2022-f0afe659-bd19-4c87-a417-a4c67a47e644). Now I'm on version 15.0.4236.7 the problem is gone.

I don't know what the bug reference is for this particular issue.